# Private and Public Tasks in Lists?

Tags: list, list-view, my-site, tasks, audience-targeting

I am trying to create a Task List which would go on a user's My Site profile. This task list will have a column where the user can select Private vs Public.

If a task is Public, anyone viewing his profile would be able to see the task, however, if its private only the user should be able to view the task.

So after reading online I found that this can be achievable using Audiences...I've now created a task list and entered several sample tasks with both private and public status. Now on the actual profile I want to create two list views of this min Task List, one for the Public Audience and one for the Private Audience. That way the owner of the profile will be able to see both views and all other users will only be able to see the public view.

Where I am confused is creating the Audiences...how do I do this? How do I create an audience that will always refer to the current users (similar to using the [Me] keyword) or do I have to create a separate audience for each individual user?

Any ideas how I can achieve this would be awesome!!! And if there is a better way not using Audiences please let me know what you think!

Thank You!

Comment: Following this question because I would like to learn more about the application of 'audiencing' in SharePoint. Though could your particular requirement be met by list item-level permissions?

Comment: Yes, I ended up using list item leve permissions instead of audiencing. I'm not too sure how to use audiencing correctly as I have never before, and this was my first attempt haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Audiences would not give you the security that is otherwise enforced by the Permissions. Anyone knowing the item's address would be able still to access it.
 Audiences are mostly used in scenarios such as content targeting, but does not change permissions access based on these rules, e.g. it only hides/shows web parts or records, depending on which audiences you are part of.

What you would need to do is create a simple workflow via SP Designer 2010 using the "Wait for field change" activity and give/remove permissions to the other SharePoint Groups on that particular site, as soon as the value of the Flag-fields gets changed.

If you still want to deal with Audiences, you must know that these are changeable only via SP-CA and only if User Profile Service Application is configured properly and UPSA Syncronization is setup as well. These being in place, you could easily via the UP Service Application choose "Manage audiences", create your own, and compile them. There is also possible to use as Audience SharePoint  Groups from your site collection.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any guides or articles on doing what you mention using the workflow that I can work through?  

  I'm a bit confused as I haven't create workflows before. So when a the field would change from Public to Private a workflow would run and change the permissions for the SharePoint Groups? Basically this list will be on My Sites so I'm not sure how I can accomplish this...thanks for any help!

Comment: there are 2 issues to consider: the actual workflow and  replicating behaviour if you plan to implement this across all "My Sites" site collections for each user.
Here http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2010/03/configure-item-level-permissions-for-document-libraries-part-2/ and http://johnliu.net/blog/2010/7/13/sharepoint-2010-configuring-list-item-permissions-with-workf.html find 2 examples doing just that

Comment: Thanks Marius, I have read through those but there is one thing I am not understanding. So I have the currently logged in user who can see all of his tasks and the other users who can see just his public tasks.  

To actually get this working in the workflow, do I add a Replace permissions for the current user who can see both public/private and give him contribute permissions and for the other users I give them what permissions? Can I remove all permissions from them? Or how do I get it so they don't see the private tasks?

Comment: I tried removing my own permissions to see if I could just not see any tasks but that doesn't seem to work. Do I need to create a specific group to contain all users and remove the permissions for them or can I use the groups already created (approvers, visitors, owners etc.)

Comment: Could you actually check you Web Application User Policy Settings in the Central Admin whether anything such as All Authenticated Users (check for Full Read) or any general group at the Site Collection Visitors level has been added by any chance? This would override whatever settings you put at list level

Comment: Alright, under the MySite collection I have these permissions Approvers,  Designers,  Hierarchy Managers,  My Sites Host Member,  My Sites Host Owners,  My Sites Host Visitors,  My Sites Host Workflow Users,  Resricted Readers,  Style Resource Readers,  System Account,  Tudor Hofnar. Out of these the only ones that have Full Control are My Sites Host Owners and Tudor Hofnar. Everything else is at most Contribute. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Unser Central Admin and Permissions for User Proile Service Application I see two groups, NT AUTHORITY/Authenticated Users and All Authenticated Users, both of which are 'Use Personal Features' 'Create Personal Site' and 'Use Social Features' Permissions. Should I remove these?

Comment: 1. For SP-CA you need to look under "Manage web applications" - select the one for My Site and in the ribbon the User Policy NOT to have these 2 groups with Full Read

Comment: 2. For "My Site Collection" - if not intentionally changed it should be ok. There are 2 sections of each my site - Private and Public, you can see that in your libraries. Just have a look IN the groups, and see if those 2 groups are also added there - they SHOULD NOT be beyond the Visitors